# Getting message "unauthenticated" for every request in laravel passport

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-passport, laravel-middleware

I am using laravel version 6 and laravel/passport version 8. I am getting {
"message": "Unauthenticated." for every request.
}
I have various guards.
**My config/auth.php**

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'vendors_web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'vendors',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'vendors' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'vendors',
        ],
    
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

    ],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'vendors' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Vendor::class,
    ],
],
```

For every outgoing request from the laravel, I have used passport's predefined middleware **\Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class**, which attaches a cookie to the outgoing response which contains the accessToken. So for every incoming request, i have wtitten a middleware **auth.api** which gets the cookie data(token) and attaches it to the request header.
**auth.api middleware**

```
 <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Middleware;
    
    use Closure;
    
    class AddAuthHeader
    {
        /**
         * Handle an incoming request.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @param  \Closure  $next
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        { 
            if (!$request->bearerToken()) {
                if ($request->hasCookie('_token')) {
                    $token = $request->cookie('_token');
                    $request->headers->add(['Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token]);
                }
            }
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
```

**Kernel.php**

```
protected $middleware = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\ForceJsonResponse::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
    
];

protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        // \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
    'auth.api' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\AddAuthHeader::class,
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
        'auth:api',
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,

    ],
];


protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'userAuth' => \App\Http\Middleware\userAuth::class,
    'adminAuth' => \App\Http\Middleware\adminAuth::class,
    'scopes' => \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckScopes::class,
    'scope' => \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckForAnyScope::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
    'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    'json.response' => \App\Http\Middleware\ForceJsonResponse::class,
    'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
];


protected $middlewarePriority = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\AddAuthHeader::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    // \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    
];
```

**api.php**

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => ['auth.api', 'auth:vendors', 'cors', 'json.response']
], function(){
    Route::get('/vendor-dashboard', "VendorController@dashboard");
    
    //get authenticated user
    Route::get('/user', 'Auth\AuthAPIController@user');

    //products
    Route::get('/vendor-get-products/{type}', 'VendorController@vendorProductListing');
    Route::get('/vendor-create-product-view/{id}/{type}', 'VendorController@createVendorProductView');
    Route::post('/vendor-create-product/{id}/{type}', 'VendorController@createVendorProduct');

    //orders
    Route::get('/vendor-orders/{status}/{type}', 'VendorController@getOrders');
    Route::post('/vendor-orders/update/{status}/{type}', 'VendorController@orderStatusUpdate');
});
```

Outputs i get are,
After logging in, i get the cookie in my browser.
[Cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Du7zF.png)

If i dd the header in the middleware, it shows the authorization header with the bearer token, but i still get anauthenticated user error. [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5QyC.png)

Comment: hello! thank you for replying. But i didn't get you. Can yiu brief me please? @KamleshPaul

Comment: @KamleshPaulOkay yeah. Even if i add the token from postman, It given me the same error. And I had done it using middleware because i didn't want to attach it everytime with everyu request.

Comment: @KamleshPaul It is auth.api which adds the cookie token to the request header. please check the code.

Comment: `$request->bearerToken()` this will be true if you pass token as bearer token how your passing ?

Comment: @KamleshPaul yeah that is correct. My flow of giving the token is different. 1. user will enter it's login credentials, In the back end i''ll check the credentials and create a tokjen for the user. 2. I'll send the token as the cookie to the front end. and for every request from the front end, i'll be getting my token from the cookie in the backend. 3. for the next incoming request, my auth.api middleware will covert that cookie token and attach it as the request header. 4. now i want to hit my api:vendors middleare. Is there any technique through which i can assign the priority to api:vendors

Comment: remove `'auth.api', 'auth:vendors'` these middleware and make your own middleware

Comment: @KamleshPaulcan you help me write onw? because i dont know how passport dycrypts the token and find if the user is genuin or not

Comment: @sante can you answer this?